# How to search a part of the string in a whole string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello all
i have string like (Attribute)-Company_02.
in this i have to find the first occurrence of (Attribute)-.
How to achieve this?

Thank you,
Mihir

Comment: Do you want to match the string within `(` and `)` or the literal `(Attribute)-` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `myString.indexOf("(Attribute)-")`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf